# Passing event to function in another js file

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass the value of a comment to my newComment() function which lives in another js file. I have the following two pieces of code:

/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { anonymousUser, addComment, login } from './blog';
import './styles.css';

login();

function App() {
  anonymousUser();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2 id="content">Content</h2>
      <hr />
      <b>Add comment:</b>
      <p id="comment">Comments</p>
      <input id="newComment" />
      <input type="submit" onClick={e => addComment(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

/blog.js

```
const addComment = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  let newComment = e;
  console.log(newComment);
  client.auth
    .loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential())
    .then(user =>
      db
        .collection('comments')
        .insertOne(
          { owner_id: client.auth.user.id },
          { comment: newComment.value }
        )
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });

  newComment = '';
};

export { anonymousUser, addComment, login };
```

Both logs return only "" and I can't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are trying to get the value of the `input submit`, while you'd want the value of the `#newComment` input. You might want to use the `useState` hook to store the value locally and provide it to your `onClick` callback.

Comment: You're not passing an event, you're passing `e.target.value`, which almost certainly doesn't have a `value` property. That aside, `e.target` on a button will be the button, not some other field.

Comment: But you're not linking the input Comment value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the function a click event from your submit button, which has nothing to do with your comment input. Either store the comment input in state and submit it with the `onClick` like this:

```
const [comment, setComment] = React.useState('');

const submit = () => {
  addComment(comment);
  setComment('');
}

....
<input id="newComment" value={comment} onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)} />
<input type="submit" onClick={submit} />
```

or use a `<form>` and submit it through that:

```
const [comment, setComment] = React.useState('');

const submit = () => {
  addComment(comment);
  setComment('');
}

....
<form onSubmit={submit}>
  <input id="newComment" value={comment} onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)} />
  <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will either of these methods allow the function to clear the value after sending it off?

Comment: Not automatically, but its simple enough to add. I'll update my answer.